# How to get recaptcha token in SvelteKit contact form

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, sveltekit

I'm developing a static website using SvelteKit to get my first approach to svelte. I got almost everything working as intended.
Everything but the recaptcha protection on contact form.

I can obtain recaptcha token but I'm losing it the passing it to formData request.
My relative code is:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import * as yup from "yup";
    import {createForm, ErrorMessage} from "svelte-forms-lib";
    ...

    function getCaptcha(){
        grecaptcha.ready(function () {
            grecaptcha.execute('recaptcha-key', { action: 'contactForm' })
                .then(function (token) {

                    console.log(token) // here I get the token
                    return token;
                });
        });
    }

    const  sendMail= (values)=>
    {
        const url = '/sendmail.php';

    const formData = new FormData();
    let token = getCaptcha();
    console.log('token: '+token); // here token is null

    formData.append("token", token);

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
    body: formData,
        })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.debug(response.status)
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        sendError = true;
    console.debug(e);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Form submission is working fine except, obviously, for recaptcha token.

Thanks for any idea on how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`token` is null because your `getCaptcha` function isn't actually returning anything, since you're using callbacks to get the token.

```js
function getCaptcha(){  // <- this function isn't returning anything
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        grecaptcha.execute('recaptcha-key', { action: 'contactForm' })
            .then(function (token) {  // <- this function returns, but the value isn't going anywhere
                console.log(token);
                return token;
            });
    });
}
```

To fix this, you may want to look into using `async`/`await` syntax for promises. [MDN has a great article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) if you're interested.

You would probably want to do something like this:

```js
async function getCaptcha(){
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // grecaptcha.ready needs a callback so we create a promise to await
        grecaptcha.ready(resolve);
    });
    // grecaptcha.execute returns a promise so we can await it
    const token = await grecaptcha.execute('recaptcha-key', { action: 'contactForm' });
    console.log(token);
    return token;
}

const sendMail = async (values) => {
    const url = '/sendmail.php';

    const formData = new FormData();

    let token = await getCaptcha();
    console.log('token: ' + token);

    formData.append("token", token);

    // you have a few options for converting
    // the Promise.catch()
    // you can use a try {} catch {} block
    // or you can use .catch() on this sendMail function
    try {
        const response = fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData,
        });
        console.debug(response.status);
    } catch (e) {
        sendError = true;
        console.debug(e);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this will make the `sendMail` function an `async` function, which means you will have to `await` calls to it, or use `sendMail().then()`. I believe it's also possible to call `async` functions directly in synchronous code and have them run, it's just not guaranteed that the stuff in the function will run before the code that comes after the call.

Comment: Thank you for you extensive reply. I will first read your suggested post and try your solution. I'll be back later. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

My final code, for clarification, is slightly different in submit function, and I'm posting it for future reference, just in case.

```js
async function getCaptcha(){
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // grecaptcha.ready needs a callback so we create a promise to await
            grecaptcha.ready(resolve);
        });
        // grecaptcha.execute returns a promise so we can await it
        const token = await grecaptcha.execute('site-key', { action: 'contactForm' });
        return token;
    }

    const sendMail = async (values) => {
        const url = '/sendmail.php';

        const formData = new FormData();

        let token = await getCaptcha();

        formData.append("name", values.name);
        formData.append("surname", values.surname);
        formData.append("email", values.email);
        formData.append("phone", values.phone);
        formData.append("message", values.message);
        formData.append("token", token);
        formData.append("action", "contactForm");


        // you have a few options for converting
        // the Promise.catch()
        // you can use a try {} catch {} block
        // or you can use .catch() on this sendMail function
        try {
            let response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'post',
                body: formData,
            });

            if(response.status == 202){
                sendSuccess = true;
                document.querySelector('form').reset();
            }
            if(response.status == 400){
                sendError = true;
            }
        } catch(err) {
            sendError = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling this yourself, you can use `svelte-recaptcha-v2`.

##### Repository

https://github.com/basaran/svelte-recaptcha-v2

##### Demo

https://basaran.github.io/svelte-recaptcha-v2/demo

P. S I'm the author of the package.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm sure it will be useful for a lot of us. In this case In solved it using the accepted answer on recaptcha v3. But I will bookmark your package for future use.